# How to pass data into another screen with "this.props.navigation.goBack()" in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm creating a react native app and now I wanted to pass data between screens. If I pass data "this.props.navigation.navigate('MyScreen1',{MyData:'Hello this is a data'})" like this it is passing data correctly. But I want to pass data inside goBack(). How do I pass data into another screen with "this.props.navigation.goBack()" method in react native?

What I tried here,
The Screen I pass data into other screens I add code below,

```
 this.props.navigation.goBack({MyData:'Hello this is a data'});
```

And data retrieving screen I added following code,

```
 var myData = this.props.navigation.state.params.MyData;
 console.warn(myData );
```

But nothing will happen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `pass a call back function while navigating to screen` and execute that callback function before `navigation.back()`

```
YourCallBackFunction=(dataFromNextScreen)=>{
 console.log('dataFromNextScreen', dataFromNextScreen)
  }


this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName', { YourCallBackFunction: function })
```

Now on your screen where you wanted to execute your goBack function pass data to that callback function.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.YourCallBackFunction(dataToBePassed)
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

`Edit:` here is a snack I have created for you go into logs and see the newly passed data on navigating back.

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/14d924

Comment: If I add code something like this in my screen 1 ** {YourCallBackFunction=(dataFromNextScreen)=>{
 console..log('dataFromNextScreen', dataFromNextScreen)
  }   opencontSCR = (value1) => {
       if (value1 == 'Contacts') {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('selectContact', {YourCallBackFunction: this.YourCallBackFunction })
    }
  }; }**

Comment: And then data send screen I added follow code. { sendData = () =>{
this.props.navigation.state.params.YourCallBackFunction({selectContactDel:'this is my data'})
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
  }}** Is it ok with these code?

Comment: But here nothing will happen

Comment: Can you please make a snack on the expo with your code and share it with me I will fix it there?

Comment: Actually it is a big project. There are so many libraries and codes. I can share the full code. Give me an email and I send them to you.  This is my mail "sidath.sansu@gmail.com"

Comment: I can create a snack for you and will share it with you?.

Comment: It looks @Waheed Akhtar 's code is correct, but you have to edit or post what you have tried the result become can't work, that he could more easily to help.

Comment: The snack I have been created works perfectly according to your question @Sidath

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I added your code but nothing will happen. My goback screen is a footertab. If there is a way to open that footer tab screen I can pass data through "this.props.navigation.navigate('MyScreen1',{MyData:'Hello this is a data'})" this code. If you can have look at my project here. [link]( github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App )

Comment: Dear sir, I just fix my problem with your code. I follow every single step you have mention. Thank you so much for helping me to solve this problem

Comment: If you can please help me to solve this problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632894/how-to-open-one-of-the-footer-tab-screen-when-clicking-on-the-menu-item-in-react)

Comment: Sure, I Will look into this too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no param to send in [goback function](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#goback). So you could use `navigation.navigate` like you said or try `this.props.navigation.state.params` [set params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setparams) before `goback` function?

Comment: Actually I am a biginner to react-native. I don't have good knowledge in react-navigation. If I can open a footer tab screen when I call a function I can pass my data  " this.props.navigation.navigate('MyScreen1',{MyData:'Hello this is a data'})" like this. But I am not able to open the footer tab screen. If you can have look at my project here. [link]( https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App )