# How to open one of the footer tab screen when clicking on the menu item in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating a react native app and now I wanted to open one of the footer tab screens when clicking on the menu item. Here I attached my sample screen and can get a clear idea about my problem from that.

[image: Sample screen 1]

[image: Sample screen 2]

Here is my GitHub repository. (https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App)

Comment: As per my understanding, you wanted to switch between the tabs when` create event `
 pressed from a menu item, Am I right? Which tabs are you using?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to navigate to create event footer tab when I click on the "create event" menu Item. In my project repository, footer tabs are in folder call "FooterPages" (https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App/src/FooterPages) and there is a folder called "HomeTabs" and it contains my tab screens.(https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App/src/HomeTabs)

Comment: Here I used native-base Tabs and  FooterTab

Comment: I have looked into your code it requires few changes and debugging, Right now I am a little busy with my work so I will fix it and let you know.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, sir.

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please?