# How to navigate to Footer tab screen when click on menu item in hamburger menu in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating a react native app and now I wanted to open one of the footer tab screens when clicking on the menu item in the hamburger menu. Here I attached my sample screen and can get a clear idea about my problem from that.

Here is my GitHub repository. (https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App)

[image: Sample screen1]

I already ask this question here:([How to open one of the footer tab screen when clicking on the menu item in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632894/how-to-open-one-of-the-footer-tab-screen-when-clicking-on-the-menu-item-in-react))
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using react-navigation , and there you can define diffrent screens.there you can navigate to that screen whenever you push Create Event, that is the easiest way for handling this .https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating

or you can create a state and pass it as props to all the children, so when you click on it you need to change the state of app and make the tab activated and show its contents

Comment: I tried it with react-navigation. My problem is I am not able to open a specific screen. That means, think that I want to open the Create event footer tab when clicking on the create event in the menu it opens the whole page. not the footer one. If you can please look at my project here. (https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/tree/master/Event-App)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a big help to me.

Comment: @Sidath dear i checked your code, you can use this approaches ,unfortunately i am super busy and, one using state manager for your footer bar ,so when you have accessibility to your state everywhere, and you can change it by clicking on items of Hamburger Menu. i hope it helps , if you got problem tell me i try to do it in my free time

Comment: Ok, dear. I got you. I'll try with your way. I'll let you know if there is a problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem. I tried your steps. But nothing worked for me.